# JES - Jython - Drawing a line between points on an image

Tags: jython, jes

I am working on an assignment where I need to draw a line between points on a map. I built it up using if statements, but that limits how many times I can do something so want to use a loop.

The code I have so far is below, I can add the cities and draw a line, but it draws a line to itself rather than from a start point to the next point (and continue on)

Can anybody please help at all?

```
def level1():
    cityXvalue = [45,95,182,207,256,312,328,350,374,400]
    cityYvalue = [310,147,84,201,337,375,434,348,335,265]
    # Display the map image
    map = makePicture(getMediaPath("map.png"))
    show(map)
    number = 0
    # Ask user to enter numbers of the cities they wish to visit    
    cities = requestInteger("Enter the number of the city you would like to visit")
    # Draw a line between previously entered point and current one
    while cities > number:
        city = requestInteger("Please choose a city number")
        addLine(map,cityXvalue[city],cityYvalue[city], cityXvalue[city], cityYvalue[city])
    repaint(map)
```

Comment: that's because `addline()` requires start x,y coordinates and the end x,y coordinates. You are using the same values for the start and end coordinates.

Comment: Thanks mate, I figured as much.


  `counter = 0

  while counter < cities:

    cityRequest = requestInteger("Enther the number of the city you would like to visit next")

    cityVisits = cityVisits + [cityRequest]

    if len(cityVisits) >= 2:

      startX = cityVisits[-2]

      startY = cityVisits[-2]

      endX = cityVisits[-1]

      endY = cityVisits[-1]

      addLine(map, cityXCoordinate[startX], cityYCoordinate[startY], cityXCoordinate[endX], cityYCoordinate[endY])

      repaint(map)

    counter = counter + 1`

That's what I ended up with, it may help someone in future.